# Flurl Timeout not respected

Tags: c#, xamarin, timeout, flurl

I use Xamarin Forms app and call my api with Flurl.

I tried a lot of different solutions but I always have a timeout arround 10 seconds. I would like 30.

My code to setup my flurl client:

```
_client = new FlurlClient(ApiUrl);

            TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30 * 1000);
            _client.WithTimeout(timeSpan);
            _client.HttpClient.Timeout = timeSpan;
            _client.Settings.Timeout = timeSpan;
```

I also tried with my call by using CancellationToken in my DelegatingHandler:

```
response = await base.SendAsync(request, new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 80)).Token);
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: Are you sure the client is timing out and not the server?

Comment: Can you please have a try with  `_client.Configure(settings => settings.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`?

Comment: Have you found  a solution ?